# Logic for PHP SQL div population

Tags: php, sql

I am setting up a website that is basically a hockey league website. As you probably know, hockey teams are found in divisions, such as East, West, etc.. Currently I have set up a way to load all hockey teams as divs.

This is my current code. It simply puts each result into a div and moves on to the next until done, listing all teams side-by-side. I then want to organize them into their divisions as supplied by the database. I know this should have been a first step.

Overall my question is: How should I first load each division, and then load each team into that division div?

```
$leagueNames = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name,jpg_location FROM league');
$leagueNames->execute();
$leagueNamesResult = $leagueNames->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($leagueNames->rowCount() > 0) { 
    echo '<div id = "leaguesSelectionTable">';
    echo '<div id = "allLeagues" class = "allTeams leagueButton">All</div>';        
        foreach ($leagueNamesResult as $row) {
                echo '<div class = "leagueButton" id = "' . $row['id'] . '">';
                echo '<img class = "leagueIcon" id="' . $row['id'] . '" src=" /img/leagueIcon/test/' .  $row['location'] .' "/>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['name'] .'</p>';
                echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
} 
?>
```

The logic would be something like:

```
# SELECT division FROM league
# echo each division as a div
# echo each league within that division as a div
# loop until done
```

I don't mind trying to figure out the code, but any logical guidance would be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give more info on your database schema?

Comment: the table "league" has fields id, name, and division in it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each division has a league_id in it, you are to repeat the same steps but have a query "Select * from division where league_id = $row[id]" and then process the result.

This will do the job in your case, however nested queries like that are generally to be avoided, so a more optimal version would be to select all divisions and all leagues and have the logic to determine what is what in your php code. However the first case will be perfectly fine for your needs

Comment: Sorry my schema was not clear. the table "league" has fields id, name, and division in it. Also what would I be searching or learning about if I wanted to do this the optimal way?

Comment: So then you have to invert it: 1) Select all divisions 2) Loop through the divisions and for each select all leagues where division = row[id] 3) loop through all leagues... What you would need to consider is that you are making many queries that way, instead you might want to select all leagues in one array and all divisions in another and then have two nested loops and check which is the current division in an if statement and match them that way, instead of querying the DB for it.